# How to force deindex URLs from Google index ASAP?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, robots.txt, google-index, xml-sitemap

Remove pages from Google index

Hello,

I have bought previously owned domain.

Right now it have 150 - 200 URLs indexed by Google that are not related to my current website (powered by wordpress).

What i did until now:

- 410 Gone http status for every page i want it unindexed;
- xml sitemap with 510 status URLs to suggest that the pages have been updated and force recrawl;
- robots.txt disallow for that 410 status pages
- submit xml sitemap to Google

Now what? What else should i try to deindex that URLs?

Comment: Did you mean "410 Gone"?   "510" is not the correct status code for "Gone".

Comment: You should remove the disallow from robots.txt.  You need to have Googlebot crawl those URLs and see the error status to get them removed.  Google sometimes chooses to index pages that are disallowed in robots.txt.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller edited post